# how to put ASP.NET  project to IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I developed a asp.net project. it is connecting visual studio 2010 in the temprary server of visual studio 2010 but when I put it to the iis it does not conect. Please how can pix this matter ?
my web.config is like that;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0,      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
</system.web>

<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ConnectionString"
 connectionString="Server=SRV-WORKFLOW; Database=PTC;User ID =   MIKES\EMREAL;Password=EMAL5616.;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />

 <add name ="PTCconnection"
  connectionString="Server=SRV-PLM; Database=wcadmin;User ID = MIKES\EMREAL;Password=EMAL5616.;Trusted_Connection=True;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"   />




 </connectionStrings>



</configuration>
```

Comment: Please provide more info.  Is your app not appearing at all, or are you unable to connect to the db when running in IIS?  Are you getting any error messages or exceptions?

Comment: I am unable to connect database when I run the application in iis

Answer (score 3):

You are using `Trusted_Connection=True` which means it tries to connect to your database with the credentials from the user the apps runs under. In the case of IIS, it's normally an AppPool user. Either allow this user access to the database, change the app pool user or use SQL Server authentication.

You can get an overview of connectionstrings here : http://connectionstrings.com/

Comment: how can I change AppPool user ? I need to use windows authentication

Comment: See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx for IIS 7 and http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f05a7c2b-36b0-4b6e-ac7c-662700081f25.mspx?mfr=true for IIS 6